# How to add more columns to data grid keeping it more expressive

Tags: usability, interaction-design, tables, accessibility, grid

If I have a grid view like this and I want to add more columns. One column will display buttons and the other one - notes.

[image]

Comment: Did you have any additional questions that we didn't address in our responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a "More details" button/link that opens a modal window with additional fields.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnKOSu.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Clicking on "More details" would open a popup similar to the one below.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUhup6.png)</sup>

Comment: What about if i want to add more actions not just info

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare Modals can house all sorts of content: data, media, files, interactive tools, games, etc... You could have an "Actions" section in your modal that contains all available actions you can do with a particular piece of data.

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare Maybe you could change the term "More details..." to say something else, but this is the way I would implement this. It effectively shows only the most important information/actions upfront, then hides the additional information/actions in the modal to avoid excessive clutter in the table.

Answer (score 2):

What is shocking in your design is that 40% of the space is taken by action button and not by the main information.

**The buttons are taking to much space.** Promote the content, not the tools.

Some icons are very generic and don't need explanation. I don't speak Arabic but I can tell that the first button is "edit", second is "print", third "validate", fourth "settings" or "batch". Display only the icon and remove the text.

Place the primary / most used icons first and directly accessible, place the rest into a more menu (like said maxathousand).

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion, but it depends on how complex your build can be (i.e., what are the limitations of the build/developers).

A while back, I actually spent some time building out table-design guidelines for College Board. One thing that became very useful was allowing "excess columns" to reside in an expanded portion of a row, displayed in a stacked view rather than as columns. The benefit of this is you can view multiple expanded views at a time (might get messy, but it's doable).

It also allows for quicker reference between normal and excess information, and between the excess information of two or more rows. This also freed up modals to serve more as views for key actions (batch actions, printing, editing, etc.), as opposed to containers of information.

[image: Expandable rows in a table]